# Replace curly-braced placeholders containing dot-delimited values with values from a 2d array

Tags: php, regex, templates, replace, placeholder

I have a paragraph of text like:

```
$paragraph = "Hello there {Customer.name},
You are {Customer.age} years old. You were born in the year {Customer.birthdate}";
```

I want to replace this with contents of an array such as

```
array('Customer' => array('name'=>'Tom', 'age'=>8, 'birthdate'=>'1980-01-01'))
```

My question is what is the best way to go about doing this? If you have a suggestion on how to format the text that would also be helpful. I am guessing you would have to use some kind of regular expression, maybe `preg_filter()` or `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$format_string = "Hello there %s, You are %d years old. You were born in the year %s";
$paragraph = sprintf($format_string, 
                     $customer['name'], 
                     $customer['age'], 
                     $customer['birthdate']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this. Just match on `\{(.+)\.(.+)\}` and index the array appropriately.

Comment: You might need to escape the braces.

Comment: I'm trying to work this out now. Could you give me some sample code to help me start?

Comment: The `0`s and `1`s in the previous snippet should be `1` and `2` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the sentence in $paragraph will always be consistent with the curly brace syntax, you could use str_replace().

Answer (score 0):

To directly isolate the curly brace wrapped substrings in your text and dynamically replace them with values from a lookup array, use `preg_replace_callback()`.

If a given path does not exist or does not resolve in a scalar-type value (string/integer/float), then the helper function will return null and the

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0piFb))

```
$paragraph = "{Greeting} {Customer.name},
You are {Customer.age} years old. {Customer} You were born in the year {Customer.birthdate}";

$lookup = [
    'Customer' => [
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age' => 8,
        'birthdate' => '1980-01-01'
    ],
    'Greeting' => 'Hello there',
];


function getByDotPath(string $path, array $lookup) {
    foreach (explode('.', $path) as $key) {
        if (!key_exists($key, $lookup)) {
            return null;
        }
        $lookup = $lookup[$key];
    }
    return is_scalar($lookup) ? $lookup : null;    
}

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/\{(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)}/',
         fn($m) => getByDotPath($m[1], $lookup) ?? $m[0],
         $paragraph
     );
```

Output:

```
Hello there Tom,
You are 8 years old. {Customer} You were born in the year 1980-01-01
```